fix issue of webrtc on different networks?
can anyone know the solution I'm currently working on WebSockets and WebRTC project , webrtc connection established successfully when both users on same network im getting udp packets but if they are on different network it won't work , there is no audio and video websockets working fine may be issue with STUN/TURN Servers how to fix it there is demo when both are on same network and on different networks
i want audio and video when both are on different networks .

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Would you provide your STUN/TURN list?

For testing purposes, you may go to the following web site for a free turn server.
https://www.expressturn.com/#features
